# Config Server Firewall: Spamming my email | lfd on localhost: Suspicious process running under user www-data

Tags: debian, firewall, spam, csf

I have just installed and configured CSF and I am getting 100s of spam emails containing this message.

```
lfd on localhost: Suspicious process running under user www-data

Time:    Wed May 23 01:05:52 2012 +0200
PID:     8503
Account: www-data
Uptime:  118 seconds


Executable:

/usr/lib/apache2/mpm-prefork/apache2


Command Line (often faked in exploits):

/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start


Network connections by the process (if any):

tcp6: 0.0.0.0:80 -> 0.0.0.0:0


Files open by the process (if any):
```

Does anyone know how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the /etc/csf/csf.pignore
Here are instructions from CSF:
http://forum.configserver.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=2059